# OAuth: Not able to obtain user's email

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I am using the dependency `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and use it for Google.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <client id>
            client-secret: <client secret>
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/google
          scope:
            - email
```

I am trying to obtain the user's email with this controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/google")
public String googleCallback(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
    if (code != null) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            String email = authentication.getName();
            System.out.println(email);
            return email;
        }
    }
    return "No email";
}
```

However, when the user has logged in successfully, the controller returns `anonymousUser`.

This what I get from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`:
*AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]*

My config:

```java
public class SecurityConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/welcome").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        );

        http.httpBasic();
        http.logout().permitAll();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
```

My OAuth verification status is in progress. According to Google:

> The Trust and Safety team has received your form. They will reach out
> to you via your contact email if needed. The review process can take
> up to 4-6 weeks. Expect the first email from our Trust and Safety team
> within 3-5 days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.

So I am not sure if there is something wrong with my code or if I have to wait until Google has verified my request.

Comment: what is `jwtFilter` why have you written custom security?

Comment: @Toerktumlare because I am using JWT. See https://github.com/RezaS/spring-security-with-jwt/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/spring_security/config/SecurityConfig.java

Comment: you are aware that using a JWT as a session replacement as you are doing is not recommended, and that is why there is no implementation of it in spring security. Handing out JWTs to browsers is bad practice. For instance, how do you logout the user?

Comment: @Toerktumlare token will be stored as a cookie. On every request, client sends this token as Bearer Token, then backend validates it to see if it's valid. Logging out the user is easy. Just delete the cookie.

Comment: but if the client can read the cookie, means the token can be stolen during a XSS vulnerability, as i presume the token you send out does not have the httpOnly flag set. Also how to do you plan to logout users? if the token is stolen during for instance a request, and you delete the token... its still valid, so the user is not logged out if you delete it. So once again, how do you plan to actually logout the user?

Comment: @Toerktumlare the goal is to set it as httpOnly. To log out the user from server-side, I can also set the expiration date of token in the past to make it invalid.

Comment: First of all, setting the cookie to httpOnly makes it so that you can no longer send the token as an Authorization header. Second of all, how can you logout a user server side when your application is stateless? how can you set the token expiration date to something in the past when it is signed? if you change it, its not the same token anymore. If i steal the token i just send it and you will accept it. You can change the token i have in my possession. Please, do some research about JWTs, please read the OWASP guidelines and google why you should not use JWT as sessions before we continue.

Comment: Also, have a little think about why the developers at spring security. Which are Security experts, dont have this implementation built into spring security. Because there is a good reason for it. You can also read about the deprecation of the `implicit flow` in oauth2, you can also read the `OWASP JSON Web Token Cheat Sheet for Java` and their recommendations. You can also in general just google why you should not use JWTs as sessions. I wish you luck, i hope you will accept the risks you are taking. Good luck